# Have more then one Json object per file using Json.net

Tags: c#, .net, json, xaml, windows-store-apps

i'm working on a Windows Store App and have ran into a problem,
currently i can read a .json file like this:

```
{
  "Name": "TestItem2",
  "Category": "Undefined",
  "Sum": 10.2,
  "Date": "28/12/2013"
}
```

Using This code:

```
async public static Task addCostsInDB(string name, double sum, string desc) 
    {
        StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile file2 = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("costs.json", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        Costs newCosts = new Costs
           {
               Name = name,
               Sum = sum,
               Category = "Undefined",
               Date = System.DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "/" + System.DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "/" + System.DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()
           };  

            var obj = newCosts;
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);


            //await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, json);
            await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file2, json);

            ReadJson.ReadJson.addCostsInDB();

            bool done = await updateVariables();

            while (done == false)
            {

            }

            return;
    }
```

However, i can only read one object per file. and i need to be able to read json files like this:

```
[
{
  "Name": "TestItem1",
  "Category": "Undefined",
  "Sum": 10.2,
  "Date": "28/12/2013"
},
{
  "Name": "TestItem2",
  "Category": "Undefined",
  "Sum": 10.2,
  "Date": "28/12/2013"
},
{
  "Name": "TestItem3",
  "Category": "Undefined",
  "Sum": 10.2,
  "Date": "28/12/2013"
},
{
  "Name": "TestItem4",
  "Category": "Undefined",
  "Sum": 10.2,
  "Date": "28/12/2013"
}
]
```

Thanks :D

EDIT:
here is the class "Costs":

```
public class Costs
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public double Sum { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `List<Costs>` to serialize/deserialize....

First initialize your object

```
List<Costs> list = new List<Costs>()
{
    {new Costs{Name="name1",Category="c1",Sum=10,Date = DateTime.Now}},
    {new Costs{Name="name2",Category="c2",Sum=20,Date = DateTime.Now}}
};
```

Serialize as

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

and deserilaize as

```
var list2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Costs>>(json);
```

---

```
public class Costs
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public double Sum { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```